# Magento website, store en store view names - can they be changed?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In our magento shop we have about 8 websites, for some websites 3 store views. Some of the website and store view names are not meaningful, and I would like to change them.

So basically my question are:

- What happens if I change the website name of an existing website?
- What happens if I change the store name of an existing store?
- What happens if I change the store view name of an existing store view?

I'm not talking about the codes. I understand that they are used in the vhost/htaccess, and maybe somewhere else, so they should stay as they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by name you mean the label of stores and websites, then nothing will happen. It's a just a human friendly string. It is no used to load a store/website in Magento core. Only id and code are used.
However, I cannot guarantee that your custom modules also respect this rule.

Comment: That's what I would expect and hope, that the names are nothing more than labels. Btw, I don't see "label" mentioned anywhere, only "name".

Comment: I have changed the names of the shops, not the codes, without any issues.